# Stdin redirection from Python

Tags: python, io-redirection

Say I have a program called `some_binary` that can read data as:

```
some_binary < input
```

where `input` is usually a file in disk. I would like to send `input` to `some_binary` from Python **without writing to disk**.

For example `input` is typically a file with the following contents:

```
0 0.2
0 0.4
1 0.2
0 0.3
0 0.5
1 0.7
```

To simulate something like that in Python I have:

```
import numpy as np

# Random binary numbers
first_column = np.random.random_integers(0,1, (6,))

# Random numbers between 0 and 1
second_column = np.random.random((6,))
```

How can I feed the concatenation of `first_column` and `second_column` to `some_binary` as if I was calling `some_binary < input` from the command line, and collect `stdout` in a string?

I have the following:

```
def run_shell_command(cmd,cwd=None,my_input):
      retVal = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=my_input, cwd=cwd);
      retVal = retVal.stdout.read().strip('\n');
      return(retVal);
```

But I am not sure I am heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are heading in the right direction.

You can use pythons `subprocess.check_output()` functions which is a convenience wrapper around `subprocess.Popen()`. The `Popen` needs more infrastructure. For example you need to call `comminucate()` on the return value of `Popen` in order for things to happen.

Something like

```
output = subprocess.check_output([cmd], stdin = my_input)
```

should work in your case.

Comment: Thanks. How do I build `my_input` from `first_column` and `second_column` to achieve the desired effect?